# Finding the volume of the cap of a sphere

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

> Let's say I have a sphere of radius 2 and we drill a hole with the
> shape of a sphere of radius 1. How shall we find the volume of the cap
> of the sphere?

What I did was finding the spherical coordinates for the surface:

$\Phi(\theta, \phi)=2(\cos\theta \sin \phi, \sin \theta \sin \phi, \cos \phi)$ with $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$

To find the boundaries for $\phi$, I used the Pythagorean theorem:

[image]

To find $h$: $(\frac{h}{2})^2=2^2+1^2$, so $h=\sqrt{20}$

So I end up with this triangle:

[image]

Then $\sin \phi = \frac{1}{2}$ so, $\phi = \frac{\pi}{6}$.

Setting up the integral:

$\int _{0} ^{\pi/6} \int _{0} ^{2\pi} \int _{0} ^{2} \rho^2 \sin \phi d\rho d\theta d\phi=-\frac{8}{3}(\sqrt{3}-2)\pi$

Which is wrong... I've done a lot of steps, so I can't really tell where I made a mistake

Comment: I think this might be where you went wrong???: "To find $h$: $(\frac{h}{2})^2=2^2+1^2$, so $h=\sqrt{20}$" When it should be: $(\frac{h}{2})^2=2^2-1^2$ ***based on the picture***

Comment: I think $h=\sqrt{12}$ then

Comment: $-\frac{8}{3}(\sqrt{3}-2)\pi \approx 2.245$ is volume of the spherical cone above $z$ axis and $\phi$ between $0$ and $\pi/6$. Your integral is set up wrong. The range of $\phi$ is correct. Also your Pythagoras is wrong as others pointed out and that would matter when you set up the integral right. In this case it did not matter as you were really calculating the volume of the spherical cone and not really spherical cap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying Pythagoras, $h^2 = 2^2 - 1^2$. You instead did addition. (I am using $h$ instead of $h/2$ to keep things simpler).

So you know $h = \pm \sqrt3$.

You calculated the angle correctly $(0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{6})$ for the spherical cap above $z$ axis. You can multiply by two if you need to find the volume for both spherical caps.

Now coming to your integral, the volume that you found is of the spherical cone and not of the spherical cap. As you need to find the volume of the spherical cap, you need to make sure that $\rho$ is only between $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\cos \phi}$ and $2$. So your integral becomes -

$V = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/6} \int_{\sqrt{3}/cos{(\phi)}}^{2} r^2 \sin \phi \, dr \, d\phi \, d\theta \approx 0.431$. This is for one spherical cap.

EDIT: see a 2D diagram.

[image]

Comment: May I ask how did you find the lower bound of the first integral? ($\sqrt{3}/\cos(\phi)$)? Im getting $2\sqrt{3}/\cos(\phi)$

Comment: @Moria I just added a 2D diagram. As you can see, we are interested only in $BC$. $BC = OC - OB$. $OC = 2$ (radius of sphere). $OA = \sqrt{3} = OB \cos \phi$. So $OB = \sqrt{3} / \cos \phi$.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: $h$ does not equal $\sqrt{3}$ but $\frac{h}{2}$ does

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins Right before that it says "I am using $h$ instead of $h/2$ to keep things simpler".

Comment: @epimorphic whoops, lol never mind then

Answer (score 0):

We need to find what is the height of the spherical cap. By the Pythagorean theorem, half of the height of the cylinder is
$$2^2=1^2+\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)^2$$
so $\tfrac{h}{2}=\sqrt{3}$. Then, the height of the spherical cap is
$$H=2-\sqrt{3}.$$
Plugging this value into the formula (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap), we get
$$V = \frac{\pi H^2}{3}(3R-H)=\frac{\pi(2-\sqrt{3})^2}{3}(4+\sqrt3)=\frac{\pi}{3}(16-9\sqrt{3})$$

Comment: $V=\frac 23 \pi R^2 H$, R=2 and $H=2-\sqrt 3$ , So: .$V=\frac 83 \pi(2-\sqrt 3) $

Comment: What is this? I don't understand your formula, sorry

Comment: this is standard formula in geometry. H is the height of the cup, as you found $H=R-\frac h 2=2-\sqrt 3$. Op has a sign error.

Comment: Have you check the formula in here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap ?

Comment: Yes I did. I suggest you check my formula in classical geometry.

Comment: Formula is $V=\frac 23 \pi R^2 H$, such that if $H=R$ you get  $V=\frac 23 \pi R^3$, which is the volume of a semi- sphere.